# How can I make sure that the data is from the login user in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to save the data I've received from Arduino in the DB. We have succeeded in receiving and storing temperature and humidity data, but failed to link this data with logged-in users. Can you help me?
Here is my code.

views.py

```
from .models import arduino
from .serializers import arduinoSerializers
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

class arduinoToAndroidViewSet (ViewSet) :
    def dataSend (self, request) :
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = arduino.objects.filter(name = user)
        serializer = arduinoSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class arduinoToDatabaseViewSet (CreateAPIView) :
    serializer_class = arduinoSerializers

    def get_queryset(self) :
        user = self.request.user
        return arduino.objects.filter(name = user)

    def dataReceive(self, request) :
        queryset = get_queryset()
        serializer = arduinoSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid() :
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import arduino

class arduinoSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name.username', read_only=True)
    class Meta :
        model = arduino
        fields = ('name', 'temp', 'humi')
```

[image]

If you post it like this,

[image]

I want you to know that this is root's data.
[image]
I log in to the test account, put the data in, and press the post button.
[image]
This will not Migrate to the 'test' account. I want to migrate this data in conjunction with the 'test' account.

Comment: It clearly said "method not allowed" in the first image. Use a `POST` request instead of a `GET`.

Comment: The result doesn't change even if I use GET.

Comment: I meant don't use GET and try and use POST. In the first image, it clearly read `Allow: POST, OPTIONS` but you made a `GET` request at `/add/`

Comment: How can I change this code to POST?

Comment: Can you please show your `forms.py` or wherever you put your forms?

Comment: I didn't make any forms :(

Comment: Where did you make your get request then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use permissions to limit access

and for linking user to your data, add perform_create function (i assume name field is FK to user)

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView


class arduinoToDatabaseViewSet(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  # only logged in users has access to this view

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(name=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I added the code, but the name of the account was not registered. :(

Comment: could you provide more detail ?

Comment: I tried to attach a picture, but I can't attach it in the comments. So can I dig a new post and post a link?

Comment: it's not a good idea, add the link or picture to your question.